# Match closest group, I cant really put it to words

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to **scrape** a website with the fewest steps possible, I simplified my problem to this because i'm having issues putting the problem to words.

I am currently testing this with javascript on https://regexr.com/ to test but will be using it with java which I haven't had a problem transferring so far but after several frustrating hours I have not been able to find a solution, with the regex `/".+?".+one/gmi`and the string `a "witch" and her "broom" is one` I wanted to match the closest group in quotes `"broom"` all the way to the word `one` but I keep getting `"witch" and her "broom" is one`

```
/".+?".+one/gmi 
a "witch" and her "broom" is one
```

Expected: `"broom" is one`
actual result: `"witch" and her "broom" is one`
I only want the closest match that is in quotes instead of the first.

> please note that this is a simplified version of the problem I am working with and will not be able to match really any specific character, only groups, if you would like to see the actual code I am working with then I would be happy to include it.

> Code I am actually working with

```
"6198609109": {
"id": 6198609109,
"word": "Choose the item below that describes the process of creating an image with the lowest file size that still renders a good quality image.\na. validation\nb. multimedia\nc. optimization\nd. bandwith",
"_wordTtsUrl": "Useless Link removed",
"definition": "c. optimization",
"_definitionTtsUrl": "Useless Link removed",
"definitionImageId": null
},
"6198630061": {
"id": 6198630061,
"word": "Select the code below that configures a background image to repeat horizontally across a web page.\na. repeat: across;\nb. background-repeat: repeat-x;\nc. background-repeat: no-repeat;\nbackground-repeat: repeat-y;",
"_wordAudioUrl": "Useless Link removed",
"definition": "b. background-repeat: repeat-x;",
"_definitionTtsUrl": "Useless Link removed",
"definitionImageId": null
},
```

> *Shortened for readability/unnecessary information
> Imagine these objects (more than the 2 shown) and what I am trying to match is

```
"Select the code below that configures a background image to repeat horizontally across a web page.\na. repeat: across;\nb. background-repeat: repeat-x;\nc. background-repeat: no-repeat;\nbackground-repeat: repeat-y;",
"_wordAudioUrl": "Useless Link removed",
"definition": "b. background-repeat: repeat-x;"
```

I am trying to match the object that has`Select the code below that configures a background image to repeat horizontally across a web page.` as either the word or the definition in the object, the issue is any attempt (which I can no longer find or recreate) matches the first objects `"word":"` and everything up to to definition. I'm sorry if this makes no sense, Id prefer if you answered the simplified version

> My primary issue is that I cant figure out is using: `[^"]+` except it works for whole words and stops at that ex:  `".+?"/[^(".+?")]*one/gmi text: a "witch" and her "broom" is one output: "broom" is one`

Comment: Include the code relevant to whatever you're doing. If you don't know what you're trying to do maybe your code would help you out. Do you mean you want the first group that matches the regex? Give an example input, and your ideal output and what makes it different from the current output

Comment: Are the quotes guaranteed to be balanced and is `one` always outside quotes? Can `one` come before the closest quotes?

Comment: Step one is for you to figure out how to describe what you want in words. If you can't do that, how will you ever describe it in code?

Comment: @Sneftel OP wants to match from the pair of quotes that is closest to the word `one`. How hard is that to understand? In other words, the shortest match from the start of a quoted string to the `e` at the end of `one`.

Comment: @Sweeper exactly

Comment: If so, can you answer my questions? Are the quotes guaranteed to be balanced and is `one` always outside quotes? Can `one` come before the closest quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Try use this Regex, and it's not enough exactly write to me:

```
"[^"]+"[^"]+$
```

[Here is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WWJX4U/2)

Good Luck!

Comment: The issue is I might need to match with things that may not just be words

Comment: @Alphapixel182004. Like what?

Comment: any character honestly, the site I am scrapping is Quizlet

Comment: and it must ended with "one" or any end of the sentence? Like `"word": "conjfhs fdgsa" gh` and you will get: `"conjfhs fdgsa" gh`?

Comment: starting with```"word":"random sentence could contain anything but would probably be using html escapes if it could interfere with js","_wordTtsUrl": "Useless Link I removed","definition": "definition quote here!",``` and ending with the end of the definition quote either word or definition could contain escaped characters including \"

Comment: also the sentence I am looking for might not be the entirety of the quote ex: my know word is "peanut butter and jelly" and the object looks like ```"word":"the cats in the craddle with peanut butter and jelly because why not","_wordTtsUrl": "Useless Link I removed","definition": "definition quote here!",``` the words I am looking for could also possibly be in the definition

Comment: @Alphapixel182004. You must have a certain pattern of text to use in Regex Patterns. What is the permanence?

Comment: @Alphapixel182004 That looks very much like JSON. Don't parse JSON with regex. Parse it with a JSON parser.

Comment: here is a demo of what I had working, regexr.com/4g4e1
the issue is ```(\d)+,"word":"[^{]*?(?=The words im looking for).*?(?=","_definitionTtsUrl":")(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*``` I have to use ```[^{]*``` which means if there is a ``` { ``` in either "word":"..." or "definition":"...." that I am not aware of, the whole code will go out the window

Comment: Do you want to extract the details of `ID`, `Definition` and etc. or just the details of `Word`?

Comment: I want to capture everything between ```"word":"``` and the end of definitions last quote, BUT the capture must contain the sentence/word or whatever I am looking for, if you look at [link](regexr.com/4g4e1) and swap the word and definition values, it should still select it

Comment: @Alphapixel182004. What is the end of the match?

Comment: ```"word":"the cats in the craddle with peanut butter and jelly because why not","_wordTtsUrl": "Useless Link I removed","definition": "definition quote here!",``` the final quote for definition

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
\"[^"]+\"[^"]+one
```

This just changes all the `.` in your regex into `[^"]` - anything but quotes.

This works because it asserts that there should not be another quote between the matched pair of quotes and `one`.

I made these assumptions:

- All quotes are balanced
- `one` is always outside quotes
- The closest quote must be before `one`

Comment: What I need really is something that works exactly like   
```".+?"/[^(".+?")]*one/gmi
  text: a "witch" and her "broom" is one
  output: "broom" is one
```
where I can put whole words inside of [^] instead of only specific characters

Comment: @Alphapixel182004 Can you tell me for which string my regex is not working? What is your expected output for that string, and what is the output using my regex?